# Move automatically to next row in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want the focus to move automatically to next row position in `Recyclerview`. My `Recyclerview` contains a `videoview`. On media completion, I want the next videoview to be played.Videoview is playing next video but only in first position videoview

```
private static int position= 0;
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  private VideoView videoView;          
  view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      position= getAdapterPosition();
      //recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
      Log.d("TAG_LIST", "Element " + position+ " clicked.");
    }
  });
} 
holder.videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
    Video(holder);
  }
});

private void Video(ViewHolder holder) {
  if (++position>= items.size()) {
    // Last song, just reset position
    position= 0;
  } else {
    // Play next song
    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
    AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask (items.get(position).getUrl(), holder,position);
    task.execute(items.get(position).getUrl());
  }
}
```

Comment: Post some code of whatever you have tried.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on "focus"? Do you mean highlighting, scrolling, removal of top item or only auto-play of media?

Comment: i have videoview in recyclerview. when first video complete the focus must move to next position to play the next videoview..Like in case of normal player one video complete and next video plays

Answer (score 0):

You didnt post any code related to your problem but I can suggest you some methods for this.

1. Find first visible item position on `RecyclerView` and start video at your `VideoView`
2. Listen scroll changes on your `RecyclerView` and when first visible item index changed, stop your video, and start next `RecyclerView` item `VideoView`